# Why array_pop() doesn't work in foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

Why array_pop() function doesn't work in this case (in combination with foreach loop)?

```
    $array=[

    ['1', '2', '3', '4'],

    ['10', '9', '8','7']

    ];

    foreach($array as $a){
    array_pop($a);
    }
```

This outputs:

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 7
    )

    )
```

So, nothing happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `foreach` works on a copy of the array.

If you want to work on the real array, you have to use a reference:

```
foreach($array as &$a){
    array_pop($a);
}
```

You can also use the keys to achieve the same:

```
foreach($array as $k => $a) {
    array_pop($array[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value variable in foreach is a copy not a reference, so the solution would be to pass it by reference,

```
foreach($array as &$a){
    array_pop($a);
}
```